# Which kind of love is "defeated love"?

Tags: meaning, translation, literature

In the end of J. M. Coetzee's short story "Nietverloren" a narrator complains about how South Africa changed, and there happens the following dialogue:

> “You sound bitter.”
>
> “The bitterness of defeated love. I used to love this land. Then it
> fell into the hands of the entrepreneurs, and they gave it a makeover
> and a face-lift and put it on the market. This is the only future you
> have in South Africa, they told us: to be waiters and whores to the
> rest of the world. I want nothing to do with it.”

Is the meaning of *"defeated love"* close to *unrequited love* (German translator interpreted it this way)? If so, how unrequited love is possible to land? May land love in return? Or *defeated love* has a completely different connotation in this context? For example, closer to *destroyed love* (since it is those entrepreneurs who made the love of narrator impossible)?

Comment: This question is about literary interpretation rather than the English language.

Comment: I wouldn't say so. Basically, my question is whether "defeated love" is a common expression in English meaning of which is close to "unrequited" or it is something else.

Comment: I wouldn't say it was a common expression, but [this Ngram search](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=defeated+love&year_start=1800&year_end=2019&corpus=26&smoothing=3&direct_url=t1%3B%2Cdefeated%20love%3B%2Cc0#t1%3B%2Cdefeated%20love%3B%2Cc0) finds some examples.

Comment: I wouldn't take the translation too literally. Translators have great latitude, which they frequently take advantage of, and translators certainly aren't always perfect, either. I'd say that "defeated love" is simply love that is unsuccessful, presumably due to some agent that "defeated" it.

Comment: Thank you @KateBunting and MarcInManhattan. After I looked at books citations in Ngram it turned out that there is no constant meaning for "defeated love" but usually it is near to "unsuccessful" or "collapsed" but by no means "unrequited".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Any answer will come close to opinion but:

> Is the meaning of "defeated love" close to unrequited love (German translator interpreted it this way)?

No. Unrequited love is love that is not returned and thus remains unsatisfied - I love her, but she will never love me.

> Or does defeated love have a completely different connotation in this context?

Yes. The writer had hoped that his love of his land would last for ever. He saw the land being abused and changed - he may have tried to stop this, but whatever happened he failed and the love he had has been destroyed by the change. His love has been defeated in a battle for the land he loved.